# Cant select any options with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm having a problem with Eclipse: I have just installed it in my mac, and I can't select any option in the file or edit header or any header in the top:

[image: image here]

I have uninstalled and installed a few times both, *Eclipse IDE for Java Developers* and *Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers* now, and many different versions and its still not working.

Do you guys have any solutions for my problem?

Comment: If this is macOS 10.13 (High Sierra) and your system language is not English see [here](https://www.eclipse.org/org/press-release/20170925criticalbug.php)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with recent versions of macOS, see https://www.eclipse.org/org/press-release/20170925criticalbug.php. There's a workaround described in the page, but you can also upgrade your Eclipse to the just released Oxygen.1a version, which contains a fix for that issue the does not require a workaround.

Comment: i had the oxygen version also, but ill try that one again thank you

Comment: Yeah it worked thank you, i had the oxygen but the september version. This last one works thank you